# Cheatsheet/summary of financial laws and regulations

Tags: banking-regulations, financial-markets

I wonder whether there are or we can collect cheat-sheets for the various international regulations of the financial markets.

There is e.g. [the Dodd-Frank act](http://media.mofo.com/files/uploads/images/summarydoddfrankact.pdf) for the US. Can we gather cheat sheets for all the other international regulations such as: Basel II/III (with the directives), Solvency II, EMIR, and all those out there?

Being a (quantitative) risk manager it is hard for me to follow all of them and soemtimes speaking with customers it looks good to know the basic facts about these regulations - apart from the advantage of knowing them for oneself.

Maybe we can gather blog series as well. Then it is easier to stay up-to-date and collect the entries in appropriate software and make it searchable and so on. An example in the Basel world is this [blog](http://www.value3-advisory.com/rr-6-basel-iv-deconstructed/).

- EMIR: [This is one of the best summaries of the Collateral requirements under EMIR](http://www.emissions-euets.com/risk-mitigation-techniques-emir/collateral) .
- [Thierry Roncalli](http://www.thierry-roncalli.com/RiskManagement.html) wrote lecture notes on risk management and financial regulation. They cover many things (more or less "everything") on more than 700 pages. The lecture notes will not be updated for the next year as then a book will be published.

Comment: Not trying to be negative here, but I'm afraid the topic is too broad. For instance, Dodd-Frank itself is a vast area with a ton of discrete SRs from FRB and OCC, which target various areas. Then you have FINRA, SEC, PCAOB etc. It's a beast. In the banks we have special departments (compliance and legal) whose sole purpose is to track what's relevant to a given institution

Comment: @Aksakal your are right of course. There would be a lot of material to collect. I wonder how far we would get. This is just a try. And I know that this subject is always evolving, but are there good books or lecture notes out there?

Comment: @Aksakal please see my edit about gathering blogs. Then we could stay up-to-date.

Comment: I added a link to an EMIR summary: it really looks complete and understandable.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a few. The categories are not mutually exclusive (e.g. since most investment advisors are obviously affected by tax and short-selling).

**Investment advisors**

- Investment Advisers Act of 1940
- Investment Company Act of 1940
- SIPA of 1970
- ERISA of 1974
- JOBS Act of 2012

**Europe**

- Criminal Justice Act 1993
- Financial Services Act 1986
- Financial Services Act 2012
- FSMA 2000
- AIFMD
- EMIR
- MiFID I/II
- Solvency I/II
- ESMA MAD I/II and MAR

**Commodities**

- Commodities Exchange Act of 1936
- CFMA of 2000

**AML**

- BSA of 1970
- FCPA of 1977
- PATRIOT Act of 2001

**Taxation**

- FIRPTA of 1980
- Taxpayer Relief Act 1997
- Sarbanes-Oxley Act of 2002

**Broker-dealers and securities exchanges**

- Securities Exchange Act of 1934
- Basel I/II/III
- Dodd-Frank
- FRB Reg D Reserve requirements
- FRB Reg M Short selling rules
- FRB Reg S Reimbursement for providing financial records
- FRB Reg SHO Short selling practices
- FRB Reg T Margin requirements

Comment: Thanks for the list and I realize that I ask too much but do you have links to summaries of these regulations too? Then it would be a great collection. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't we make this answer a community wiki and this can be the place where the cheat sheets are collected and built

Comment: @MatthewLock I would agree, I just don't know how this can be done.

Comment: @vonjd do you have any idea how we can improve this question and answer? does it makes sense to make it part of a community wiki?

Comment: @madilyn do you think you find time to add links to most important regulatons?

Comment: @Richard I'll try, although this list was just off the top of my head so I don't have O(1) access to the links. Most of the (US) acts are just codified in the CFR and can be found quite easily. Unfortunately the most interesting to have are the links to relevant guidance letters published by the regulators, which will unfortunately fall outside the scope and conventional word limits for StackExchange.

Comment: @madilyn I agrree that we can not post while texts here. But do you think you could provide links to the guidance letters? Thank you!

Comment: @madilyn please see my edit about gathering blogs. Then we could stay up-to-date.